# How to return day number of every moday

Tags: excel, date

A big dilema for me, I have class with students on monday and friday, i cannot figure out with excel how to return the day number of monday or friday on this month or next month
eg. 19 sept is monday this week and next week is 26 september

I want to return next month that monday will be 3 then 10, 17

I tried a silly formula like =(19+7) return 26 but then show 33 but a month dont have 33 days.

Hope you guys understand me and maybe help me, thanks

Comment: What have you tried? If you have any code at all you should post it. That will make users more likely to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the date `2016-09-19` in A1.

Create a custom format of `d` for that cell.

Then in A2 put this formula =A1+7.

Ensure that the same format is in that cell.

Then copy down.

[image]